# What's the delete policy on Meta?

Tags: discussion, meta, policy, deleted-posts

So someone asked a question about adding themes to Stack Overflow and it got deleted. I'm curious what was the reason for that? It's a relevant question and there are others like it, e.g., 
https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11520/stack-overflows-mascot-and-theme-song

Can someone clarify the policy?

Comment: It's back already.

Comment: That was the "others like it" question, not the deleted one.

Comment: Sometimes the users that proposed a poorly received change delete the question top stop the onslaught of downvotes.

Comment: @TravisJ Oops, you're right.

Comment: I do seem to remember it saying that it was deleted by the author.

Comment: Sometimes the post is deleted when it is clearly a duplicate.

Comment: You should do the honorable thing and delete this to keep the irony. :)

Comment: The author deleted it after seeing it was a dupe.

Answer (score 7):

The post was self deleted.

> [image]

Possibly the OP did not like the response he was getting from the community and didn't want to lose the reputation or be associated with an unpopular post, possibly he was alerted to a duplicate question that provided sufficient information.

Comment: Or if the post is a duplicate and the topic has already been covered.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, how can you tell it was self-deleted?  It looks like you're just under the relevant rep threshold at the moment.

Comment: @blahdiblah He could have had a link from before it was deleted.  Going to that link will tell you if it was deleted by a mod, the community, or the author.

Comment: (Confidential to @ChrisF, thanks for tightening that up.)

Comment: I was in the middle of answering that post when I got a "this post was deleted" message. A quick refresh and I was confronted with the "the author has removed this post".

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/149791/have-a-holiday-themed-stackoverflow says the post was deleted by its author.

Comment: @Lix - Lol, your black and white statement of `Obviously...` is pretty amusing. Because it is, **obviously**, a fallacy. **I** removed that post because, in the comments, there was a link make to a duplicate. I could care less about downvotes because they are consensus. But, seeing as how consensus was already reached on the topic (via the linked duplicate), I removed the post. "Associated with an unpopular post", you make it seem as if proposing ideas is a bad thing. I think your poor attitude is a reason why people have a bad taste in their mouth from meta.

Comment: @trav - I didn't mean to offend you. I've changed the wording of my post to better reflect the possible deletion reasons. You are right... `"obviously"` was the wrong choice of words.

Comment: @TravisJ You [**couldn't** care less](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=om7O0MFkmpw)

Comment: @NullUserExceptionอ_อ - Hm, of course from a "sayings" standpoint you are correct. But the subtle distinction between the two definitely invokes some self reflection on how I weigh downvotes. I think they are important, but wont ramble any further.

Comment: @NullUserExceptionอ_อ - That video is hilarious.

Comment: @tra - Look for the one on flowers and haircuts...